# The difference of two order statistics of exponential distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

If we have a random sample $X_1,X_2, \ldots, X_n \stackrel{\text{iid}}\sim f(x\mid\theta)=e^{-(x-\theta)}I(x >\theta)$. We want to prove 
$$2\sum X_i-2n X_{(1)} \sim \chi^2_{n-2}$$
where $X_{(1)}$ is the smallest order statistic.

I tried: 
$$2\sum X_i-2n X_{(1)} =2\left[\sum X_i-n X_{(1)}\right]=2\left[\sum X_{(i)}-n X_{(1)}\right]=2\left[\sum \left(X_{(i)}- X_{(1)}\right)\right]$$ 
And I was trying to find the distribution of 
$$X_{(i)}- X_{(1)}$$

And I searched that
$$X_{(i)}-X_{(i-1)} \sim \operatorname{Exp}\left(\frac{1}{n+1-i}\right) \text{ if } X_i \stackrel{\text{iid}}\sim \operatorname{Exp}(1)$$
Any ideas? Thank you~

Comment: It should be $\chi^2_{2n-2},$ right?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I am not quite sure, it's just something my professor mentioned in class and he wrote this.

Comment: I know the following. $\chi ^{2}(2)$ is the same as exponential distribution. with $1/2$ coefficient.  It is also easy to derive that $X_{(1)}$ has exponential distribution with coefficient $n$. However I can't say that sum of $\chi^{2}$ distributed variables has $\chi ^{2}$ distribution.

Comment: First, by translation invariance of the quantity you're calculating, WLOG you can set $\theta =0.$ You're told the minimum $m = X_{(1)}$... so you know that you have $n-1$ others that larger than this minimum. By memoryless property, conditional on this information the others are exponential with location $m,$ so their difference with $X_{(1)}$ is standard exponential. So you have the sum of $n-1$ independent standard exponentials ($\Gamma(n-1,1)$). By the relationship of Gamma and chi-squared, two times this is $\chi^2_{2n-2}.$ (I comment rather than answer since this is far from rigorous.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thank you for your answer. I was trying to use the sum of the exponential is Gamma at first but I have a little doubt, are they independent?

Comment: @Nan That's the not-so-tight part of the argument, but I think so. The key to tightening it up, I think, is doing a law of total probability decomposition over events of the form "$X_i$ is the minimum and $X_i =m.$" I think it's doable to show $(X_j-X_i)$ for $j\ne i$ are conditionally independent standard exponentials on this event.

Comment: (Hopefully it's clear that I'm not saying that $X_{(j)} -X_{(1)}$ are independent in any sense... that's certainly not true.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, I simulated the case $n = 10,\, \theta = 0$
to see if this seems to work at all and to confirm your correction of the degrees of freedom. $\mathsf{Chisq}(n-2)$ doesn't fit the histogram of the simulated values, but $\mathsf{Chisq}(2n-2)$ does. Of course, this doesn't _prove_ anything, but (to me
anyhow) it offers hope your argument might be made rigorous.

Comment: Definitely it should be $\chi^2_{2(n-1)},$ not $\chi^2_{n-2}. \qquad$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Should that be $\Gamma(n-1,2)$ to make a $\chi^2_{2n-2}$?

Comment: Yes, and two times a $\Gamma(n-1,1)$ is a $\Gamma(n-1,2).$ (It's confusing cause there's two common parametrizations. Here the second parameter is scale ("$\theta$"), not rate ("$\lambda$").

Comment: My post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2793341/321264) should be relevant.

Comment: I would try to show that $$X_i - X_{(1)} \sim \begin{cases} \delta_0 & \text{if } X_i = X_{(1)}, \\ \chi^2_2 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$ Then I would wonder how to show that $X_i-X_{(1)},\, X_j-X_{(1)}$ are independent. Then you standard properties of the chi-square distribution. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Comment:* @spaceisdarkgreen, I simulated the case $n = 10,\, \theta = 0$
to see if this seems to work at all and to confirm your correction of the degrees of freedom.
The red curve is for $\mathsf{Chisq}(n-2)$ and the green for
$\mathsf{Chisq}(2n-2).$ Of course, this doesn't *prove* anything, but (to me
anyhow) it offers hope your argument might be made rigorous.

[image]

R code in case it is of any use:

```
m = 10^5;  n = 10
x = rexp(m*n);  MAT = matrix(x, nrow=m)
t = rowSums(MAT);  v = apply(MAT, 1, min)
y = 2*t - 2*n*v
hist(y, prob=T, br= 25, col="skyblue2", ylim=c(0,.12))
 curve(dchisq(x, n-2), 0, 50, lwd=2, col="red", add=T)
 curve(dchisq(x, 2*n-2), lwd=2, col="darkgreen", add=T)
```

Comment: Let $J = \text{the index $j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ for which } X_j = X_{(1)}.$ Then $J$ is uniformly distributed in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Then we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_{(i)}- X_{(1)} \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - X_J) \quad (\text{Note that one of the $n$ terms in this last sum is $0$.})
$$
And
$$
\Pr\left( \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-X_J) \in A \right) = \operatorname E\left(\Pr\left( \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-X_J) \in A \right) \mid  J \right)
$$
and this last probability does not depend on the value of $J.$ Since it does not depend on $J,$ this expected value is equal to $\qquad$

Comment: its conditional probability given that $J=1,$ i.e. to
$$
\Pr\left( \sum_{i=2}^n (X_i - X_1) \in A \mid J=1 \right).
$$
By memorylessness of the exponential distribution, the distribution of $X_i-X_1$ given that $X_1<X_i$ is the same exponential distribution as that of $X_i.$

Comment: @michaelhardy, yes this is the part I was stuck on too (see my comments above). Seems "obviously" true since all you know is that they're all greater than some value... knowing one doesn't give info about the others. Yet couldn't see how to make this rigorous.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be a random sample from exponential distribution with mean $1.$ 
Then joint probability density of order statistics $X_{(1)},X_{(2)},\ldots,X_{(n)}$ is 
$$f_{X_{(1)},X_{(2)},\ldots,X_{(n)}}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)= n! e^{-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}, 0\leq x_1\leq x_2\leq \cdots \leq x_n \leq \infty$$
Let us consider transformation

$$Y_1=nX_{(1)}, Y_2=(n-1)(X_{(2)}-X_{(1)}), Y_3=(n-2)(X_{(3)}-X_{(2)}),\ldots,Y_n= X_{(n)}-X_{(n-1)}$$

$$\Rightarrow X_{(1)}=\frac{Y_1}{n}, X_{(2)}=\frac{Y_1}{n}+\frac{Y_2}{n-1},\ldots, X_{(n)}=\frac{Y_1}{n}+\frac{Y_2}{n-1}+\frac{Y_3}{n-2}+\cdots+Y_n$$

Jacobian of above transformation is $\frac{1}{n!}$.

So joint probability density function of  $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_n$  is given by

$f_{Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_n}(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)= e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n y_i}; 0\leq y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n\leq \infty $.

This follows, using factorization theorem, $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,\ldots,Y_n$ are identically and independently distributed as exponential variate with mean $1.$

$\Rightarrow Y_i=(n-i+1)(X_{(i)}-X_{(i-1)}) \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} \operatorname{exp}(1)$; $i=2,3,\ldots,n$.

Hence $\sum_{i=2}^{n} Y_i= \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-X_{(1)})$ is sum of $(n-1)$ independent $exp(1)$ variates, so $\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-X_{(1)})\sim \operatorname{gamma}(n-1)$.

Ref: "Order Statistics & Inference" by Balakrishnan & Cohen.
[https://www.amazon.com/Order-Statistics-Inference-Estimation-Methods/dp/149330738X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/149330738X)

Answer (score 0):

First try to show that $$X_i - X_{(1)} \sim \begin{cases} \delta_0 & \text{if } X_i = X_{(1)}, \\ \chi^2_2 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$ Then think about how to show that $X_i-X_{(1)},\, X_j-X_{(1)}$ are independent. Then use standard properties of the chi-square distribution.